# limit_req, exclude php file and route

Tags: nginx, php

I have a script that show images and i'm trying to exclude the following php route from limit_req

```
rewrite ^/([^\@]*)\@(\d+x\d+)$ /index.php?route=image&action=show&path=$1&size=$2 break;
```

I have

```
location ~ .php$ {
    limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=3 nodelay;
    limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 3;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

for images and other file formats I used

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|css|less|xml|html?|swf|js|ttf)$ {
    expires 10y;
}
```

so how can I exclude the route (index.php?route=image) from limit_req in nginx config?